# Capybara -- how to check for content containing a line return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

Say that my HTML outputs...

```
<p>foo<p>...
```

...and it's important to check that 'foo' is the last text in the line.

What's the quickest way to check for the line return using Capybara?

```
Then I should see "foo\n"
```

is not working for me.

The error is:

```
expected #has_content?("Cached Slug: foo\\n") to return true, got false (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

The following works, but of course doesn't check for the line return:

```
Then I should see "foo"
```

Comment: havent tested this or anything myself but it looks like capybara is escaping the '\' character in its search.  have you tried putting the phrase in single quotes or tried something like "foo/\n"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
Then I should see "foo
"
```